# Using mySQL, Php and JS, how do I request dans use data I have in my DB?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

**What i want to do :** when a user select a location in a select field, the function newMark() place a marker on a google.maps;

**What i achieve by now :** Display the map, the select field with all the location saved in my DB.

I have a DB with a table named `Step` with the columns `namePlace`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`.

Here is the code I have at the moment :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr">

<head>
    <title>Carte dynamique des Itinéraires</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">     

        function initialiser() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.779231, 6.659431);
            //objet contenant des propriétés avec des identificateurs prédéfinis dans Google Maps permettant
            //de définir des options d'affichage de notre carte
            var options = {
                center: latlng,
                zoom: 3,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            //constructeur de la carte qui prend en paramêtre le conteneur HTML
            //dans lequel la carte doit s'afficher et les options
            var carte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("carte"), options);


        }

        function newMark(lat, lng){
        var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: carte)})
        }
        var sel = document.getElementById("namePlace");


        sel.onchange = function() {
        var lat = this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("dtlat");
        var lon = this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("dtlon");
        newMark(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lon));
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="initialiser()">   
    <div id="carte" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    <div>
    <form>
        <label for="namePlace"><p><u> Nom etape : </p></u></label> 
        <p>
        <select name="namePlace" id="namePlace">
        <option value="">Selectionnez un lieu</option>
        <?php
        include("connexion.php");
        $con = connect_LIF4();
        $req2 = "SELECT * FROM etape";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $req2);
        while ($donnees = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
        {     
               echo'<option value="'.$donnees['NomLieu'].'" dtlat="'.$donnees['Latitude'].'" dtlon="'.$donnees['Longitude'].'">'.
                $donnees['NomLieu'].'</option>';                
        }
        ?>              
        </select></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the output code with the solution which add field to html tags :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PROJET LIF4</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" />
</head>
<body class="homepage">
        <div id="header-wrapper" class="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <nav id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Page d'accueil</a></li>
    <li><a href="itineraire.php">Choisir un itineraire</a></li>
    <li><a href="carte.php">Carte</a></li>
    <li><a href="avis.php">Avis</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
                    <div id="logo">
                        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr">

<head>
    <title>Carte dynamique des Itinéraires</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <!-- Elément Google Maps indiquant que la carte doit être affiché en plein écran et
    qu'elle ne peut pas être redimensionnée par l'utilisateur -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <!-- Inclusion de l'API Google MAPS -->
    <!-- Le paramètre "sensor" indique si cette application utilise détecteur pour déterminer la position de l'utilisateur -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialiser() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.779231, 6.659431);
            //objet contenant des propriétés avec des identificateurs prédéfinis dans Google Maps permettant
            //de définir des options d'affichage de notre carte
            var options = {
                center: latlng,
                zoom: 3,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            //constructeur de la carte qui prend en paramêtre le conteneur HTML
            //dans lequel la carte doit s'afficher et les options
            var carte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("carte"), options);


        }
        function newMark(lat, lng){
        var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: carte})
        }
        var sel = document.getElementById("namePlace");

        sel.onchange = function() {
        var lat = this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("dtlat");
        var lon = this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("dtlon");
        newMark(lat, lon);
        }


    </script>
</head>

<body onload="initialiser()">

    <div id="carte" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    <div>
    <form>
        <label for="namePlace"><p><u> Nom etape : </p></u></label> 
        <p>
        <select name="namePlace" id="namePlace">
        <option value="">Selectionnez un lieu</option>
        <option value="Abaine" dtlat=56.9333300 dtlon=26.8500000>Abaine</option><option value="Abu Fanajin" dtlat=30.4327100 dtlon=45.5775200>Abu Fanajin</option><option value="Abu Shanab" dtlat=10.7883300 dtlon=29.5524400>Abu Shanab</option><option value="Adoyevshchina" dtlat=52.2865800 dtlon=46.5031800>Adoyevshchina</option><option value="Agaro" dtlat=15.8333300 dtlon=38.6500000>Agaro</option><option value="Agarsararen" dtlat=7.9500000 dtlon=46.2833300>Agarsararen</option><option value="Agasur" dtlat=10.7185000 dtlon=45.5652000>Agasur</option><option value="Ahl `Arub" dtlat=14.2833300 dtlon=47.0666700>Ahl `Arub</option>               
        </select></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried a lot of thing, like using xmhttprequest, jquery, but it seems i cannot do it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the latitud and longitude in your database also? In that case, you can populated your options with that information too:

**EDITED**

In your question you posted this line as a result of trying my solution:

```
<option value="Abaine" dtlat=56.9333300 dtlon=26.8500000>Abaine</option>
```

That is wrong. As you can see the values are not wrapped by quotes. It should be as I put it in my answer:

```
<option value="Abaine" dtlat="56.9333300" dtlon="26.8500000">Abaine</option>
```

Notice now the quotes surrounding the `lat` and `lon` values.

Look at the **while loop** bellow:

```
while ($donnees = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {     
    echo'<option value="'.$donnees['namePlace'].'" dtlat="'.$donnees['Latitude'].'" dtlon="'.$donnees['Longitude'].'">'.
        $donnees['namePlace'].
    '</option>';       
}
```

**HERE**: `dtlat="'.$donnees['Latitude'].'"`. Notice the double quotes. And that is assuming that your column names are `Latitude` and `Longitude`. Otherwise, just put the right names:

Finally:

And the *JS*:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("namePlace");

sel.onchange = function() {
    var lat = this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("dtlat");
    var lon = this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("dtlon");
    newMark(lat, lon);
}

function newMark(lat, lng){             
    var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
    map: carte});
}
```

*FINAL OBSERVATION*:

`google.maps` function could be waiting for float values and we are sending a string here `newMark(lat, lon)`. In case that doesn't work either, try `newMark(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lon))`.

And the last thing: I find weird this line: `position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),`. I didn't realized untill now. It seems that you already instantiated the object `google.maps` so it should probably be: `position: google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),`. But I'm not so sure about that, so keep that in mind just at last resort. Let me know how you're doing it. We'll solve this.

Comment: @Kaendor I edited my answer. *Read untill the last line*. You look being close to get this working.

Comment: My bad for these quote! I was wondering if i can access the variable "carte" since it's in the initaliser() function. And for your last thing : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon), I think it instanciate a LatLng object and not a map object. I'm not sure

Comment: I have no idea what that variable is for. I'll be off for an hour or two and I'll be back. Let me know how it works or you. Cheers.

Comment: var carte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("carte"), options); carte is the map, and since it's in another function, i'm wondering if i can have access to it...

Comment: You may update your question being more specific with what you tried and what was the result, etc. I'm willing to help.

Comment: Are you still doing this: position: `new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),`? I honestly find sort of bizarre the `new` there. can you put it without the `new`please?

Comment: I removed it, but since my map for a reason i can't find won't appear, i can't see if there any changes.

Comment: Can you provide me a link to where that plugin documentation is located?

Comment: Sure, here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: This seems to be the right way to do it: `var mark = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: -34, lng: 151}, map: map});`. Replace the numbers with your variables `lat` and `lon`. Put it inside your function `newMark` after removing what you have now.

Comment: I did it, and figured why the map didn't showed up anymore (semi-colon problem...) but no the mark do not appear on the map. But again, maybe it's because I instanciate a map in the function initialiser() and i'm trying to access it in another function. I don't know how to do it in an other way though...

Comment: I succeeded ! Thanks you a lot ! I just had to put the example JS you gave me in the initialize function... Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try something like this in your while loop.

```
$lat = $donnees['Latitude'];
$lon = $donnees['Longitude'];
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>newMark('$lat', '$lon');</script>";
```

You can put it anywhere on the page you might want to call the JavaScript. It is important to make sure that the function is defined somewhere on the page as well.

If you would like to embed this in a button you might want to do the following:

```
$lat = $donnees['Latitude'];
$lon = $donnees['Longitude'];
echo "<button type='button' onclick='newMark($lat, $lon);'>Click Me</button>";
```

Comment: It is important to make sure that you use double quotes to define the outer string and single quotes inside. Otherwise PHP won't parse (interpolate) the variables in the string. However, you still need quotes in the JavaScript as well.

Comment: the function is defined, but i can't make this solution work... I tried in the while loop, i was afraid it would mark all the places, but it didn't mark anything.

Comment: Can you post the output of the HTML source produced by the PHP script and add it to your question?

Comment: I host the website myself, so i don't know it you can have access to the output website.

Comment: When the page is displayed, right click the page and select view source. After that anonymize anything that shouldn't be public and then paste the anonymized source in the original question. It will give others an opportunity to assist you.

Comment: I did it. But it's currently with the other solution which i prefer since it would put markers when the user select the option.